# Button created after PageLoad - Click Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autopostback

I have a button that is created **after** a user selects a certain value from a dropdown menu, but it is not firing its' EventHandler. Is there something with the Lifecycle, OnInit possibly, that I have to refresh for the handler to fire correctly?

Event fired from DropDownList's **OnSelectedIndexChanged**

```
protected void Selected_floor_first(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "room_button_1";
    btn.Text = "Select";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(room_1_Click);
    floor_1_room_overlay.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Handler: **(Not Firing)**

```
protected void room_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        validation.Text = "You selected a Room";
    }
```

Comment: Could you possibly just edit a pre-existing buttons visiblity instead of dynamically creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is dynamically added, you have to take that code in Page_Init() event that occurs after every postback. otherwise when the postback occurs, there is no room_button_1 in the forms.controls collection and the event is missed. So

1. add it as it is being added.
2. after adding set a variable in session to identify that dynamic control has been added
3. on page_init() check the session variable of step2. if it says yes then create the control you created in step 1.

Instead of repeating the code, it's better if you create a function for button creation and call it from your `Select_floor_first()` and `Page_Init()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* create your button dynamically, create it inside the **OnInit()** method of the page.

Event handling happens after Page Init. So, the button will have to be created before Page Init, for the events to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The button goes out of scope mate. define it as a private variable otherwise the event wont fire as the button disposed after Selected_floor_first method finishes

```
private Button btn = new Button();

protected void Selected_floor_first(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn.ID = "room_button_1";
    btn.Text = "Select";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(room_1_Click);
    floor_1_room_overlay.Controls.Add(btn);
}

protected void room_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        validation.Text = "You selected a Room";
}
```